# Swift: How to create scrolling buttons?

Tags: swift

I am a beginner and don't know how to go about this:
how would you have a line of say 5 buttons be able to be scrolled through? I know there is a Scroll View but how would you put buttons into it?

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolling through" a line of buttons?  If they are all in a single line, what scrolling is involved?

Comment: I want all of my buttons to be in a bar on the top of my page, so it would be a horizontal scroll bar so you could scroll through the line of buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Scrollview followed below steps :

1) On bar, put vwScrollView named control :

2) Put, your all 5 buttons on it, on vwScrollView . . .

3) Now, Code for it : 
   In viewDidLoad method : `[self vwScrollView] setScrollEnabled: YES];`

4) Now in viewDidAppear method :

`[scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(yourWidth, yourHeight))];`

I hope, this works for you . . .

Comment: Hi, alright so I thought this worked but now I'm having some issues, would you mind visiting my most recent question? I need help